# Function returns proxy instead of object in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js

I have an array: `const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']`

And I have a function that takes an array of strings and return array of objects:

```
const func = (arr) => arr.map(item => ({str: item}));
```

For some reason when I call this function and print the result I get an array of `proxy` objects instead of normal objects..

```
// call and print
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const res = func(arr);
console.log(res);

// console result
(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
0: proxy {str: 'one'}
1: proxy {str: 'two'}
2: proxy {str: 'three'}
```

The thing is that it's only happening if I use return inside the `func` function because when I print the mapped array inside `func` without a `return` statement I get the expected result:

```
(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
0: {str: 'one'}
1: {str: 'two'}
2: {str: 'three'}
```

**NOTE:** I'm using react.js with next.js and importing `func` from another file.

Comment: Neither my browser nor my Node does this. What are you running it on?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin react app with next

Comment: I meant: what runtime environment are you using? Since you've included the numbers from the output, it doesn't look like output from node. React and Next are some frameworks that don't seem to be related to your question in any way.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin node

Comment: Node is printing `0:`, `1:`, `2:` directly into the console on the server side, without any intermediaries? Can you then please change your code to log the node version with `console.log(process.version, res)`, and tell us what the output is? I somehow have the impression that there must be some kind of intermediary between node and the output that you have copy-pasted above.

Answer (score -2):

I check your code and I see the problem is return on [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You can try the below function:

```
const func = (arr) => arr.map(item => ({str: item}));
```

Or

```
const func = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(item => ({str: item}))
};
```

I use it in the below demo:

```js
const func = (arr) => arr.map(item => ({str: item}));

// call and print
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const res = func(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: it was a mistake here, not in the original code. see edit.

Comment: @user12499410 `The thing is that it's only happening if I use return inside the func function` -> The `func` is fixed, so what is your problem now?

Comment: yes if I dont return anything and just print the result inside the func function then its normal